display image in markdown with indent
I have something like this:

I want the image tied to the "higklmn" paragraph.
But the image can't show properly.
Please help

please don't post images of code. also: what do you mean with "can't show properly"

The exclamation mark must be under the "h". And the line preceding the image must end with two spaces (visualized as ·· below) to force a line break.
* abcdefg
  * higklmn··  
    ![Image](https://httpbin.org/image)


abcdefg

higklmn




